# argmax $f_n (x) \rightarrow$ argmax $f(x)$ if $f_n \rightarrow f$ pointwise?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, convergence-divergence, optimization, convex-analysis

Let $X$ be a normed vector space and  $f_n,f:X\rightarrow \mathbb R$ such that $f_n \rightarrow f$ pointwise. We can suppose that $(f_n)$ is $C^1$, strictly concave and argmax $f_n (x)=x_n^* \in X$. On the other hand, $f$ is not smooth.

What is a necessary and sufficient condition to get argmax $f_n (x) \rightarrow$ argmax $f(x)$ (in the norm of $X$) in this setting?

Comment: A sufficient condition would be uniform convergence. I'm not sure whether it is necessary or not.

Comment: Uniform convergence is by far not necessary: Consider $f_n(x) = -(1 + 1/n) x^2$ on $X = \mathbb R$. I do not think that there are any reasonable necessary conditions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the following, I consider the case of minimization of convex functions. Hence, you need to add some minus signs here and there.

A sufficient condition is [$\Gamma$-convergence](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/%CE%93-Konvergenz) of the functionals. It ensures that accumulation points of a sequence $(x_n)$ of minimizers of $(f_n)$ is a minimizer of $f$. Note however, that a sequence of minimizers may lack accumulation points.

In case $X$ is a reflexive Banach space, [Mosco convergence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mosco_convergence) might help.